# Как изменить строку в пайтон файле

Tags: python

У меня есть 2 файла, 1 конфиг и мейн файл, допустим я хочу изменить в конфиг файле 1 значение переменной, как это сделать так чтобы после перезапуска программы значения сохранились?
Main.py

```
`if start_session == 1:
    start_calc()
if start_session == 2:
    config.edit()
    x = int(input("1-Открыть калькулятор, 2-Изменить цены"))
    if x == 1:
        start_calc()
    if x == 2:
        print('Для выхода введите "0"')
        edit = input('Введите новое значение в формате: Тномер_лвл=Новое Значение (Т5_2=1000)(БЕЗ_ПРОБЕЛОВ): ')
        len_edit = len(edit)
        new_volume = edit[6:len_edit]
        edit = int(new_volume)
        if edit == 'Т2_1'  or 'т2_1':
            config.t2_1 = new_volume`
```

Config.py

```
def edit():
t2_1 = 100
t2_2 = 200
t3_1 = 1001 
t3_2 = 12123
t4_1 = 1423
t4_2 = 2132
t5_1 = 2132
t5_2 = 12421
t6_1 = 24521
t6_2 = 2142
t7_1 = 2421
t7_2 = 43123
t8_1 = 521342
t8_2 = 324532
```

Comment: используйте json,yaml,xml или на крайний случай pikle для хранения конфигов

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с конфигами лучше использовать специальные инструменты, например, модуль `configparser`

```
import configparser
```

Читать:

```
settings = configparser.ConfigParser()
settings.read(filename) # например, settings.ini
x = settings['DEFAULT']['param1']
y = settings['DEFAULT']['param2']
```

Сохранять:

```
settings['DEFAULT']['param1'] = 123
with open(filename, 'w') as config:
    settings.write(config)
```

Структура файла конфигурации:

```
[DEFAULT]
param1 = 24
param2 = 56

[CUSTOM]
param1 = 59
param2 = 11
```